# Start Emacs, create new file and execute functions

Tags: start-up

I would like to automate the following when emacs start:

- open a new buffer
- launch a foo function (create-name) that writes something
  on the buffer and copy to clipboard a name YYY for the buffer
- save the buffer with name YYY

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: See (emacs) [Emacs Invocation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Invocation.html).

Answer (score 1):

In my `.emacs` file:

```el
(defun make-buffer-notes()
  "Make notes-file at NOTES default folder (on desktop for windows)"
  (setq notes-path "c:/default/path/for/notes/")
  (setq notes-timestamp (concatenate 'string "NOTES-" (format-time-string "%Y-%_0m-%d-%H%M" (current-time))))
  (setq notes-full-path (concatenate 'string notes-path notes-timestamp  ".org"))
  (find-file notes-full-path)
  (insert "* " notes-timestamp  " :NOTES:\b\n"))

(make-buffer-notes)
```

Answer (score 1):

The earlier answers give some good help. Here are a few more hints that you may find helpful:

`(generate-new-buffer "foo")` will create a new buffer that is not associated with any file. This new buffer if not made current buffer so, in order to write into it, you want to do `(switch-to-buffer (generate-new-buffer "foo"))`.

`(kill-new "YYY")` will not only push "YYY" on top of the kill ring, it will copy it to the clipboard.

`(write-file "YYY")` will save the current buffer in file YYY where YYY might be a relative or an absolute path.

`(kill-buffer)` will delete the current buffer.

Comment: My goal was to quickly create an annotation file with a timestamp... your suggestion makes things faster! Thank you!

Comment: Elisp is great for generating time stamps, e.g., `(format-time-string  "%a-%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: Using `(format-time-string "%Y-%_0m-%d-%H%M")` as filename in my default notes-folder I have a history of my notes for subsequent research or statistical processing.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [Keyboard Macros](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros) are for!

Start recording `C-x (`
Accomplish what it is you want to do
Stop recording `C-x )`
Name your new macro `M-x name-last-kbd-macro`
Save it to init `M-x insert-kbd-macro`

Now you can even assign it to a keybind!

Example:
`(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") 'my-macro)`

Don't worry about getting the steps when defining the macro perfect. If you make a mistake just correct it and keep going, all that matters is the end result is what you desire.